# Selenium python send_keys to Vaadin TextField

Tags: selenium, vaadin

I can't get python-selenium to work with a Vaadin textfield. Selenium finds the element, clicks it but then the keys are not sent.

I tried to put a .click before sending the keys but its not working.

## Python-selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://localhost:8080")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('name')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('Hello')
```

Vaadin:

```
TextField name = new TextField();
name.setId("name");
```

No error message i shown.

Edit:
Solved this with Actionchains

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('name')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click().send_keys("hello").perform()
```

Comment: Which Vaadin version you use?

Comment: by can't get it to work do you mean that the text is not set to the text field in the browser or that the value in the server-side TextField doesn't change?

Comment: Vaadin 14 and the text is not set in the browser (visually).

Comment: When doing elem.clear() I get an error message that says "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Unable to clear element that cannot be edited: <vaadin-text-field id="username">"